# Why "this" is returning undefined from my functional component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm still beginner in ReactJS and JavaScript and I'm having trouble using `this`.

I'm rendering a list of properties and when I do `onMouseOver` I'd like to get the element I'm hovering over with `this`. But it's returning `undefined`.

Can you tell me why I'm getting this error?

Here's my code I put into [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-pasteur-ftr83k?file=/src/App.js)

Thank you very much in advance.

[image]

```js
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

import Property from "./components/Property";

import { mock } from "./data/mock";

export default function App() {
  const [data] = React.useState(mock.data.dora.exploreV3.sections[2].items);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      {data.map((item) => (
        <Property key={item.listing.id} item={item} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
import React from "react";

const Property = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        padding: "5px 0",
        cursor: "pointer"
      }}
      onMouseOver={() => console.log("item: ", this)}
    >
      {item.listing.name}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Property;
```

Comment: 'this' refers to the scope the code is executing in in javascript. What you are looking for is the Event.target which will give you the Dom element the event is happening on.

Comment: Functional components are here to stay, don't try to use the this keyword, makes no sense in React.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your code does not work as you expect is because `this` is not bound to the element during rendering. You need to access the element using the MouseEvent target. Your Property component should look like this:

```
import React from "react";

const Property = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <div
      style={{
        padding: "5px 0",
        cursor: "pointer"
      }}
      onMouseOver={(event) => console.log("item: ", event.target)}
    >
      {item.listing.name}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Property;
```

Alternatively, you could use React's `useRef` to do this. Here's a good article explaining how to implement that: https://linguinecode.com/post/get-current-element-react-onmouseover-or-onmouseenter

Answer (score -1):

Fat arrow functions are not able to access "this" keyword.
Try updating the function as a regular function.

This might be helpful : https://www.section.io/engineering-education/how-to-use-javascript-arrow-functions-and-this-keyword/